# Recently i have updated my pc after update wifi option is missing

Tags: networking, drivers, updates, 20.04

Recently after updating my pc wifi option is missing in system setting. My wifi card is Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 and i use ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless-AC 9462
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b1218000-b121bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:2b:67:95:91:8c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: a8:7e:ea:21:71:c1
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.141 multicast=yes
```

And my linux kernel version is

```
5.4.0-48-generic
```

And the output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` is

```
dpkg -l | grep linux
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                     2.34-6ubuntu1                         amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  console-setup-linux                           1.194ubuntu3                          all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  fonts-linuxlibertine                          5.3.0-4                               all          Linux Libertine family of fonts
ii  libselinux1:amd64                             3.0-1build2                           amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libselinux1-dev:amd64                         3.0-1build2                           amd64        SELinux development headers
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                                1.18.0-2build1                        amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                          1.18.0-2build1                        amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                    4.5ubuntu3.1                          all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                1.187.3                               all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-20.04                       5.4.0.48.51                           amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-47                        5.4.0-47.51                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-47-generic                5.4.0-47.51                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-48                        5.4.0-48.52                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic                5.4.0-48.52                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04               5.4.0.48.51                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic                  5.4.0-26.30                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic                  5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic                  5.4.0-45.49                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic                  5.4.0-47.51                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic                  5.4.0-48.52                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04                 5.4.0.48.51                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                          5.4.0-48.52                           amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic                5.4.0-26.30                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic                5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-45-generic                5.4.0-45.49                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-47-generic                5.4.0-47.51                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-48-generic                5.4.0-48.52                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic          5.4.0-26.30                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic          5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-45-generic          5.4.0-45.49                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-47-generic          5.4.0-47.51                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-48-generic          5.4.0-48.52                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-sound-base                              1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                    1.10.0-1build1                        amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  syslinux                                      3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2   amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
ii  syslinux-common                               3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2   all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                               2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                  amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  util-linux                                    2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1                     amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

output for `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*`is

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:0074]
    Kernel modules: wl, iwlwifi
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface [8086:02e0]
```

please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you install any drivers before?

Comment: i have checked for additional drivers in software update center and found none how to check weither i have installed any drivers or not coz prior to the update i didnt had this issue.

Comment: You should know that. It is not so easy to check. You shouldn't install any drivers for this adapter. If you installed them, that may be a problem.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: if i am trying to run `dmesg | grep iwl ` in terminal it is not giving any output even if run with root privilege

Comment: This means that the kernel was not properly installed. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux`.

Comment: This looks good. Let's try to search further. `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*` `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and `modinfo iwlwifi`

Comment: Even i dont see any issue by any change if i restart the pc will it resolve the issue

Comment: Please don't add this to comments.

Comment: so should i remove those comments and add them in the main question

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new information up there. If you want to draw attention of a specific commentor, write a new comment starting with @userID of that person.

Comment: i have updated my question and i have restarted my pc but still the problem is persisting @Pilot6

Comment: In my update there was an update to linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-48 generic and one of the solution for similar problem has asked to remove it and reinstall it should i suppose to do it @Pilot6

Comment: The problem has been resolved by turning of secure boot and installing bcmwl-kernel-source but i don't why so can someone explain what was the problem and how my solution worked @Pilot6

Comment: bcmwl-kernel-source was already installed and it is completely unrelated to Intel adapters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved by turning of secure boot and installing bcmwl-kernel-source but i don't why. So can someone explain what was the problem and how my solution worked.
This is the command i have run in the terminal
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`